# Javafx Load TableView based on event from other TableView

Tags: java, controller, javafx-2, tableview

Basically I have 2 TableView elements. One with Teams and the second one with People. 
Each of these tableViews has its own FXML file, and are created within a controller. As an example, here is the `TeamViewController.java`:

```
public class TeamsViewController implements Initializable{

    // Service layer for accessing datastore
    private ServiceLayer serviceLayer = new ServiceLayer();

    @FXML private TableView<Team> tableView;
    private TableColumn<Team, Integer> idCol;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    tableView.getColumns().addAll(
            this.createIdCol(),
            this.createTeamNameCol(),
            this.createButtonColumn()); // Click to show Team members

    tableView.getItems().setAll(serviceLayer.getAllTeams());

}
// ......... bunch of methods to create the columns, etc.
```

And here the FXML file:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="342.0000999999975" prefWidth="568.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="main.ui.TeamsViewController">
  <children>
    <TableView fx:id="tableView" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="282.0" prefWidth="568.0" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Now, both table work fine when I add them separately to the main scene of my application this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {

        // This shows the Team table
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("teamViewController.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        //This will show the People table
        AnchorPane people = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("peopleViewController.fxml"));
        scene.setRoot(people);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.severe(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The last column of the Teams Table has a button. So, where I am stuck is: 
How can I show the team members table (People) when I click on the "Detail" button in my Team table? 
Thanks in advance for any tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using FXML's for both tableviews , you need to switch these fxml at click event of the 'Detail' button.

You also need to change your application file for changing fxmls.

You can use this code

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    try {
        stage = primaryStage;

        gotohome();

        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void gotohome() {
    try {
        FXMLController home = (FXMLController) replaceSceneContent("Homepage.fxml");
        home.setApp(this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void gotoproductwise() {
    try {
        SampleController product_wise = (SampleController) replaceSceneContent("/product_wise/product_wise.fxml");
        product_wise.setApp(this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


private Initializable replaceSceneContent(String fxml) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(fxml);
    loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource(fxml));
    AnchorPane page;
    try {
        page = (AnchorPane) loader.load(in);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }

    // Store the stage width and height in case the user has resized the window
    double stageWidth = stage.getWidth();
    if (!Double.isNaN(stageWidth)) {
        stageWidth -= (stage.getWidth() - stage.getScene().getWidth());
    }

    double stageHeight = stage.getHeight();
    if (!Double.isNaN(stageHeight)) {
        stageHeight -= (stage.getHeight() - stage.getScene().getHeight());
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(page);
    if (!Double.isNaN(stageWidth)) {
        page.setPrefWidth(stageWidth);
    }
    if (!Double.isNaN(stageHeight)) {
        page.setPrefHeight(stageHeight);
    }

   // stage.setOpacity(1);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.sizeToScene();
    return (Initializable) loader.getController();
}
```

So you must send object of main application class to controller and from there you can call switching methods.

add this code to your Controller class

```
 private Main application; 
public void setApp(Main application) {
this.application=application;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Code Lord, that makes sense. I have however a question regarding "send object of main application class to controller". What is the best way to do so? Can you send some sort of application context? Thanks

Comment: Yes , i am sending main application context to controller class through controller function setapp(). You have to create setapp function  and main application object at contrller. In above  answer  i am giving that controller code.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Code Lord!